# What is the intuition behind tarjan algorithm for finding Strongly Connected Components?

Tags: algorithm

I am learning tarjan's algorithm from here [Tarjan](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tarjan-algorithm-find-strongly-connected-components/), and I have two questions:

1. How we are finding strongly connected components using stack?
2. Why should there be no back edge from a descendant of sub-tree rooted with V to its ancestor?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the second question, think of it this way:
If you DID have an edge that went back to some ancestor node, that means that you can get there from the sub tree in question, and therefore the whole thing becomes a strongly connected component.